# Find source code line which prints some debugging stuff on stdout

Tags: python, debugging, stdout

I have a huge code base before me, and can't find the place where this strings gets printed to stdout:

```
[{}]
```

I can reproduce it, but searching the relevant code line was not successful up to now.

I guess this was added accidentally by a developer to aid debugging.

Any clue how to find the matching code line which emits this string to stdout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the relevant source code line be raising an exception, if this line gets emitted like this:

```
class WrapperOfStdout():
    def __init__(self, old_stdout):
        self.old_stdout=old_stdout

    def write(self, data):
        assert not '{}' in data, data
        return self.old_stdout.write(data)
```

Add this wrapper into your script, and wrap stdout as early as possible (soon after main):

```
sys.stdout=WrapperOfStdout(sys.stdout)
```

You will get an Exception like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/u/src/foo-bar/foo_bar/utils/common.py", line 94, in issue_to_tar
    meta = issuemeta(request, issue).encode('utf8')
  File "/home/u/src/foo/foo/views/issue/view.py", line 198, in issue_meta
    div = index_model.view(issue, request)
  File "/home/u/src/foo/foo/utils/indexutils.py", line 96, in view
    form = form_cls(request, issue, None, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/u/src/foo-x/foo_x/logic/forms.py", line 115, in __init__
    print(fake_initial)
  File "/home/u/tmp/issue_to_tar.py", line 13, in write
    assert not '{}' in data, data
AssertionError: [{}]
```

Now you see where the unwanted output happens. In this case it is `logic/forms.py` line 115.